# How can I use my postgresql database to list datas in my jQuery Mobile project that converted to the android application with phonegap?

Tags: android, jquery, postgresql, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am new at this subject I didn't find a way to do it.How can I use my postgresql database to list datas in my jQuery Mobile project that converted to the android application with phonegap? I already converted a html and javaScript to the android with phonegap to test it, but I have a postgresql database and I need to list datas in this android application, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSql is used as a **backend** database. **Backend** in *web programming* will mean that it is used in conjuction with a **webserver** and a **middleware**.
**Middleware** will be used to connect to the database and respond to webserver request with data.
For Middleware you could use a number of technologies such as PHP, JSP, Java, Rails, etc. There are many more.
The data flow would be something like below.
**Response Request**
*Mobile App( Phonegap) -> WebServer -> Middleware(PHP, Java, etc) -> Database.*
**The response Data.**
Database->Middleware->Webserver->Mobile App.
The response data can be sent in the format of  your choice.
The most common and popular formats are **JSON and XML**